# Add LoyaltyCard to Google Wallet

Tags: android, google-pay, google-wallet

i have a problem adding a loyalty card into google wallet. I've followed all the instructions google has but in onActivityResult i get a generic responseCode 3 that i can't find any details.

```
{
  "iss": "hidden@hidden.gserviceaccount.com",
  "aud": "google",
  "typ": "savetowallet",
  "iat": "1687270367",
  "origins": [],
  "payload": {
    "loyaltyObjects": [
      {
        "id": "hidden.TestLoyalty6",
        "classId": "TestLoyalty",
        "state": "ACTIVE"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

[image]

[image]